# running a process that will run parallel to the application, will make network call and sleep again

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

In my application, I need a `thread` that will always run parallel to the application (or in other words, will always run in background). The process that will run on this thread will do the following things:

```
1) check for a specific value in my sqlite database
2) if the value is what i need, it will make a network call and get some data from a web service
3) parse the received data and save it in sqlite database
4)sleep for a few minutes
5) repeat the process again
```

How can I achieve this? Do I use NSOperationsQueue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatch_async as follows

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {

        do {
            if "value is what you need" {
                "make the network call and process the data"
            }
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(100)
        } while true
```